# Maven + javadoc: add offline links

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, javadoc

For each job in our jenkins server I also want to build the javadoc. The projects are maven projects so I use mvn javadoc:javadoc to generate the javadoc. This works just fine but now I want to link with external javadoc of third party API's we use (e.g. wicket). For that I added a property to the (parent) pom.xml as explained [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/javadoc/faq.html#offlineLinks):

```
<properties>
    <maven.javadoc.offlineLinks>http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/</maven.javadoc.offlineLinks>
</properties>
```

However, this doesn't work. In the generated javadoc the references to Wicket classes are rendered as simple text and not as links to the offline javadoc.

Comment: The link you gave is of Maven-1 but i assume you are using at least Maven 2 or 3 ..

Comment: Yes, maven 3 but I did not find a specific page for offlinelinks for maven 3 so I assume/hope the property hasn't changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following configuration for [maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/):

```
<offlineLinks>
  <offlineLink>
    <url>http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/</url>
    <location>../javadoc/jdk-5.0/</location>
  </offlineLink>
</offlineLinks>
```

Comment: Which configuration are you referring to? Tx.